# Is it wrong to use filter an map in react hook return statement using ternary operator?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I thought it was okay to use code like this. is searching is true then i am filtering else i am simply mapping the data. but it shows error on .filter and .map and && in "products&& products.map(). What concept i am missing here?

```
{
   searching
    ?{
       products.filter((product, index) => searchBrand === product.brandName).map((product, index) => {
          {products &&
              products.map((product, index) => (
                  <React.Fragment key={index} >
                      <GridCard
                          mobileName={product.mobileName}
                          brandName={product.brandName}
                          price={product.price}
                          colour={product.colour}
                          ram={product.ram}
                          rom={product.rom}
                          key={index}
                      />
                  </React.Fragment>
              ))
      }})

     }
    :{products &&
    products.map((product, index) => (
        <React.Fragment key={index} >
            <GridCard
                mobileName={product.mobileName}
                brandName={product.brandName}
                price={product.price}
                colour={product.colour}
                ram={product.ram}
                rom={product.rom}
                key={index}
            />
        </React.Fragment>
    ))}
}
```

Comment: did you find my answer helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, returning same data 2 times based on conditional statement which is not right way to do.

you need to format your data based on conditional statement instead mapping and filtering than and there in return.

Example: write one method called `renderFormattedData` and change productsData based on conditional statement inside than map and return formattedData.

```
const renderFormattedData = () => {
    let productsData = products; // productsData
    // getSeaching Key as argument if it's class component or no need if it's functional
    // change productsData based and searching
    if(searching) {
        productsData = products.filter(item => item.brandName === searchBrand);
    }
    if(products && products.length) {
        return products.map((product, index) => (
            <React.Fragment key={index} >
                <GridCard
                    mobileName={product.mobileName}
                    brandName={product.brandName}
                    price={product.price}
                    colour={product.colour}
                    ram={product.ram}
                    rom={product.rom}
                    key={index}
                />
            </React.Fragment>
        ));
    }
    return null;
 }
```

i made working example for you to understand. check it once.

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-mountain-pgd1u?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `()` bracket instead of `{}`.
Try like this.

```
{
   searching
    ?{
       products.filter((product, index) => searchBrand === product.brandName).map((product, index) => (      //here
          {products &&
              products.map((product, index) => (
                  <React.Fragment key={index} >
                      <GridCard
                          mobileName={product.mobileName}
                          brandName={product.brandName}
                          price={product.price}
                          colour={product.colour}
                          ram={product.ram}
                          rom={product.rom}
                          key={index}
                      />
                  </React.Fragment>
              ))
         }
      )) //here
     }
    :{products &&
    products.map((product, index) => (
        <React.Fragment key={index} >
            <GridCard
                mobileName={product.mobileName}
                brandName={product.brandName}
                price={product.price}
                colour={product.colour}
                ram={product.ram}
                rom={product.rom}
                key={index}
            />
        </React.Fragment>
    ))}
}
```